# Quick Question in regards to the Methods in Abstract Classes

Tags: java, class, oop, abstract

I am a amateur programmer and I recently stumbled upon this special way of overriding a function when studying abstract classes:

```
abstract class Test {

    abstract String message();
}

public class Abstract {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       String word = new Test() {

           String message() {
               return "Hello World";
           }

       }.message();

    }

}
```

I am confused at specific this part in the code:

```
String word = new Test() {

           String message() {
               return "Hello World";
           }

       }.message();
```

From looking at this specific section of the code, it seems that the abstract class is being "instantiated" (if I am using the term correctly). However, I learned that abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

I know this is quite of an obvious question, is it possible if you can explain to me what is happening when that part of the code is being complied? I would be really grateful if you do so.

Thank you,

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 3):

> From looking at this specific section of the code, it seems that the abstract class is being "instantiated"

Not really. What you see is an instantiation of an anonymous class that extends the abstract `Test` class, and implements the abstract `message()` method of that class. The anonymous class is not abstract, and can therefore be instantiated.

An equivalent code would be:

```
public class SubTest extends Test (
    String message() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}

public class Abstract {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String word = new SubTest().message();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using anonymous class(so it doesnt mean that you create object from abstract class).
You are creating object with type Test that is implemented by class without name, that has body and overrides abstract method `message()`. And after body you type "." and calling method from real object, that you implemented in anonymous class.

it is similar to:

```
abstract class Abs{
  abstract void somemethod();
}

class AbsImpl extends Abs{
@Override
void somemethod(){
  print("hello");
}

Abs abs = new AsbImpl();
abs.somemethod();

// or

new AsbImpl().somemethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer above:

Abstract classes can be "instantiated" directly in your code. These are called "anonymous classes".
When you create an anonymous class, you are forced to implement every abstract method of this abstract class. This also counts for interfaces.
You can "instantiate" an object of an interface type. All you have to do is implementing the methods.